# Homework problem. What is the answer supposed to look like?

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation

I am taking a statistics course this semester, and this is part of our first homework assignment, only I don't know what the answer is even supposed to look like.

> When the process is functioning correctly, the adhesive strength X is
>   normally distributed with a mean of 200 N and a standard deviation of
>   10 N. Each hour, you make one measurement of the adhesive strength.
>   You are supposed to inform your supervisor if your measurement
>   indicates that the process has strayed from its target distribution.
>
> a. Find P(X ≥ 203), under the assumption that the process is
>   functioning correctly.
>
> b. Based on your answer to part (a), if the process is functioning
>   correctly, would a strength of 203 N be unusually large? Explain.
>
> c. If you observed an adhesive strength of 203 N, would this be
>   convincing evidence that the process was no longer functioning
>   correctly? Explain.

Just to be clear, I don't necessarily need the answer, just what the answer would look like. I have no idea what `Find P(X ≥ 203)` means really. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a hint. X is random variable with known properties. You are asked what is the probability that X exceeds 203. Intuitively, X tends to hover around 200, so the probability that X is slightly greater than the mean of 200 should be a bit less than one half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given a normally distributed attribute X with a known mean and standard deviation. As you may already know, the area under the normal curve is one (unity). By P(x ≥ 203), you are asked the area under the curve to the right of x=203. To determine that, calculate the number of standard deviation units x=203 lies above the mean (i.e., the z-score). Then from a z-table, you can read the area under the curve above the z-score you calculated which is the area to the right of x=203. That is p(x≥203).